# Switching from MAC development to IOS development

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am a MAC developer for more than 4 years. I am planning to switch to iOS development. I am confused how to start with this. Please suggest from where I can start. What are the main things should I be concentrating on. If there is any links on switching from MAC development to iOS development will be very much appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: Some of it depends on what you want to create but, generally, a complete understanding of view controllers -- types of them, uses of them -- will go a long way in helping with the transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have to follow **basic tutorials with iOS programmation**.

It will be very easy to switch on with those tutorials - [Raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/38557/learn-to-code-ios-apps-1-welcome-to-programming) !

Go to the *Part3*. You just have to know the fundamental about iOS, the rest is the same as Mac programming !

It's my opinion, but if you aren't a junior in Objective-C it should be very easy for you with those tutorials !

Good luck ;)